# Monitor goes black

Tags: hdmi, dvi, external-display

When I open Chromium or any graphical application my external monitor goes black!

It works fine with `gnome-terminal`.

This problem happens on `Windows 10` too, specially when I open chrome.

The cable is `HDMI` to `DVI-D`.

Video showing the problem [here](https://youtu.be/bzM354Lg3q8).

Comment: Have you adjusted display settings?? https://www.windowschimp.com/how-to-set-a-display-as-the-main-display/

Comment: this doesn't answer my question